# How to call MVC ActionResult when there's an update from the database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I need to know how to update or refresh the views, or call ActionResult ONLY when there's an update from the database.
Do I need some kind of a listener(or windows service) to trigger or call the ActionResult from ASP.NET MVC? But how to do it?
Is there any other way to do it?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The HTTP protocol is stateless. This means that the client sends a request, the server processes this request and sends back a response to the client. So the response is sent because the client sent a request and not because some event (such as database update) occurred on the server. You may take a look at [SignalR](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx) if you want to implement push notifications to one or multiple clients.